# Revit: Cannot create dimensions when ViewSection is rotated

Tags: dimensions, revit-api

I'm trying to set dimension to the elements in a AssemblyInstance. The code operates with coordinates from the first element.

```
AssemblyInstance ass; //is found and is not null

ViewSection vsec = RevitAuxilaries.CreateAssemblyViewSection(uiapp, ass, 
AssemblyDetailViewOrientation.ElevationFront, ElementId.InvalidElementId, 25); 
//UIApplication, 
AssemblyInstance, AssemblyDetailViewOrientation, TemplateId, scale // created
BoundingBoxXYZ bbox1 = ass.get_BoundingBox(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView);
XYZ ptmid = (bbox1.Max + bbox1.Min) * 0.5;

Element cropboxelm = RevitAuxilaries.GetViewCropBox(uiapp, vsec); //finds CropBox element, 
//found

BoundingBoxXYZ bcropbox = vsec.CropBox;
XYZ center = new XYZ(ptmid.X, ptmid.Y, 0.5 * (bcropbox.Max.Z + bcropbox.Min.Z));
Line axis = Line.CreateBound(center, center + XYZ.BasisZ);

RevitAuxilaries.RotateElement2(uiapp, cropboxelm, axis, 0.6981); // UIApplication,, Element, 
Line, angle// created
double dw = RevitAuxilaries.GetDimensionFromElement(uiapp, fi, Dimensions.enWidth); //found dw 
 // = 3.937
ptleft = new XYZ(31.501, -23.3878, 32.4803);
ptrght = new XYZ(31.501 + dw * Math.Cos(0.6981), -23.3878 + dw * Math.Sin(0.6981), 32.4803);
Line ln = RevitAuxilaries.CreateLineFromPoints(uiapp, ptleft, ptrght); //created
ReferenceArray refarr = new ReferenceArray();
refarr.Append(ln.GetEndPointReference(0));
refarr.Append(ln.GetEndPointReference(1));
Dimension dim = null;
using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "CreADim"))
{
    trans.Start();
    dim = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document.Create.NewDimension(viewsec, line, refarr);
    if (!issame)
    {
        try
        { dim.ValueOverride = Convert.ToInt32(UnitUtils.Convert(dim.Value.Value, 
            UnitTypeId.Feet, UnitTypeId.Millimeters)).ToString(); } 
        catch { }
    }

    trans.Commit();
    uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.RefreshActiveView();
}
```

ERROR: The direction of dimension is invalid
Error in function checkDir, line 939
What is here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the exact same dimension in the exact same context manually through the end user interface? Does that complete as expected? If  not, what error message does that generate? If yes, you can analyse the resulting model, its elements and their properties using [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) and possibly discover some required settings that can be added to your API approach.

Comment: Yes, I used aligned dimension button from the menu band in revit frontend and was able to set dimensions for assembly instantce elements on the rotated view section. I tried to analyse the drawn dimensions with RevitLookup as well, but was inconclusive.